# Any way to optimize multiple put calls to Google App Engine beyond batching?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I hold messages in a map for each user in the datastore.  It's held as an unindexed serialized value keyed by a unique name.  A user can message many users at once.  Currently I execute a batch get for the (e.g.) 20 targets, update the serialized value in each, then execute a batch put.  The serialized message size is small enough to be unimportant, around 1KB.

This is quick for the user, the real time shown in appstats is 90ms.  However the cpu-time cost is 918ms.  This causes warnings and may become expensive with high usage, or cause trouble if I wish to message 50 users.  Is there any way to reduce this cpu-time cost, either with datastore tweaks, or an obvious change to the architecture I've missed?  A task queue solution would remove the warnings but would really only redistribute the cost.

**EDIT:** The datastore key is the username of the receiver, the value is the messages stored as serialized Map where key is username of sender and Message is simple object holding two ints.  There are two types of request.  The 'update' type described above where the message map is retrieved, the new message is added to the map, and the map is stored.  The 'get' type is the inbox owner reading the messages which is a simple get based on key.  My thinking was that even if this was split out into a multi-value relationship or similar, this made improve the fidelity (allowing two updates at once) but the amount of put work would still be the same provided it's a simple key-value approach.

Comment: Do the fields on which you are querying have indexes defined for them?

Comment: It's impossible to answer this without more details. What are you storing in the message queue? What's it's format? How do you need to access it?

Comment: @Travis No indexes specified as I'm only getting/putting by key.

Comment: You need to show code then. A straightforward key-query should not be using 10x cpu-ms

Comment: @Nick Updated question to answer questions

Comment: @Travis I think this is actually working as expected.  If you look at the post [here](http://blog.appenginefan.com/2010/04/patterns-of-doom.html) this shows how batching the gets or puts will parallelize multiple requests.  The api time is 10x real.  I may have gotten api/cpu mixed up mind you.  The costly bit is what I'm concerned by, looking for ways to reduce that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're already doing things fairly efficiently. It's not likely you're going to be able to reduce this substantially. Less than 1000 cpu milliseconds per request is a fairly reasonable amount anyway.

There's two things you might gain by splitting entities up: If your lists are long, you're saving the CPU cost of reading and writing large entities when you only need to read or modify some small part of it, and you're saving on transaction collisions. That is, if several tasks need to add items to the queue simultaneously, you can do it without transaction retries, saving you CPU time.